# Delphi Controlling Excel - Creating Pivot Tables and Charts

Tags: excel, delphi, com, pivot-table

Delphi 10 / Seattle, with Excel 2013. I am writing a plugin (using AddIn Express) for Excel.  One of the things that I need to do is create a series of Excel Pivot Tables/Pivot Charts.  I have recorded macros within Excel, so I have VBA code to do what I want.  My challenge is porting it to Delphi.

My code compiles, and when I step through it, the very last line gives me the error .. Method 'SetSourceData' not supported by Automation Object. FYI - XLApp is a variable point to the Excel Application.

```
procedure  TMyTemplateForm.Pivot_TouchesByQuarter;
var
myPivotCache: OleVariant;
myActive_WB : OleVariant;
MyChart : OleVariant;
ChartSourceRange : OleVariant;
TabDestination : string;
begin
  // Add the new Sheet
  XLApp.Connect;
  myActive_WB := XLApp.ActiveWorkbook;
  XLApp.Worksheets.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam,1, xlWorksheet, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT );

  // Get a handle to the new sheet and set the Sheet Name
  sheet_graph1 := XLApp.ActiveSheet;
  sheet_graph1.Name := 'Graph1'; // CANNOT CONTAIN SPACES.. ?????

  // Parameters: SourceType, SourceData, Version
  // Doc at:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839430.aspx
  myPivotCache := myActive_WB.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase,'Raw Data!R1C1:R1048576C36',xlPivotTableVersion15);

  // Parameters: TableDestination, TableName, DefaultVersion
  TabDestination := 'Graph1!R3C1';
  myPivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TabDestination, 'PivotTable1',xlPivotTableVersion15);

  // Select where we want this placed...
  sheet_Graph1.Cells.Item[3, 1].Select;

  // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228277.aspx
  // Create the chart object
  myChart := sheet_Graph1.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered);

  // Define the Range that is the source for the chart.  This is the Pivot Table I created just above
  ChartSourceRange := sheet_Graph1.Range['Graph1!$A$3:$C$20'];
  // Tell the Pivot Chart to use the Chart Range
  myChart.SetSourceData(ChartSourceRange);


end;
```

Why am I getting this error?  As a related question, can I point my Chart Source to the PivotTable1 object?  Right now, it is hard coded to specific cell locations, but depending on the data, my Pivot table can be bigger than from Row3 to Row20.

If it helps any, the VBA macro code (last 2 lines) is..

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$3:$C$20")
```

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mcve]. You've got too many undeclared variables and types in your post as it is now.

Comment: When you use TOlevariant the compiler dont know the methods and properties. Use instead the Excel.tlb library for an early binding and you can see the during development which methods and properties are available. Of course you have then to use the myChart : TChart variable.

Comment: @@Christine - I have always struggled with understanding early binding vs late.  I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.  I DO include Excel_TLB in my uses clause.  If you have any reading materials you can recommend, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @user1009073 [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/245115) is an KB article from Microsoft (unfortunately in german, but you will find it in other languages). I prefer early binding, because I can use the type library and during development and I can create a solid code which I can test by the compiler during development. The disadvantage is that I maybe cannot use the e.g. 2016 object model when my customer still uses 2007.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.   Instead of

```
  // Tell the Pivot Chart to use the Chart Range
  myChart.SetSourceData(ChartSourceRange)
```

the code should be

```
 myChart.chart.SetSourceData(ChartSourceRange);
```